# Artisan migrate error: Illuminate\Database\QueryException

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, xampp, database-migration

I am trying to migrate and already installed Xampp and also already uncomment the `";extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll"` and `";extension=pdo_mysql"` in the `php.ini` file, and still getting that error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
> could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = rav2 and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
>
> PDOException::("could not find driver")

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you don't set correct db states at .env.

Check your .env params that you want to connect your database.

for example, table_type = 'BASE TABLE' seems to be wrong?

first, check your php.ini is correct like

```
# Windows
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll

# Linux
extension=php_pdo_mysql.so
```

Is that uncommented ?
if you have `;`,remove that.

and you need to restart your xampp after fixing that php.ini.
do `/etc/init.d/httpd restart`

also your laravel env may be wrong ... so fix .env like:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE= your database name
DB_USERNAME= your database user name
DB_PASSWORD= your database password
```

and you should check your database config like:

/config/database.php

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'your database name'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'your database user name'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'your database password'),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

Comment: Thank you, sir, for answering and the suggestions, but all of that is I already done and the error message still the same. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: actually mysql is correct running on xampp? are there any errors?

Comment: for example, quick check way is like this:
1. set <?php php_info(): ?> on your index.php
2. find ```PDO support```,and driver value
3. if in that value is  no value or nothing, it is not correct running xampp mysql
4. if in that value is mysql or pdf_mysql,  it is correct running

Comment: if you check all, next you need to find your running server

・linux server
do ```yum -y install php-pdo
yum -y install php-mysql``` and restart server

・windows server
fix your php.ini like 
```
;extension=pdo_mysql
　→
extension=pdo_mysql
``` and restart apache server

Comment: if you do all, can you check your status under following code?
```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=yourdbname;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'root';
$password = 'password';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    echo "connection successfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "connection failed";
    echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
}
```